# Is it standard to distinguish two versions of the hypothetico-deductivist conception of science : confirmation approach and falsificationism?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, induction, deduction, popper

In his course on *Philosophy Of Science*, Pr Folse ( Loyola University New Orleans) distinguishes two trends in the " empricist consensus " ( that emerged in the 19th century) :  inductivism and hypothetico-deductivism.

He also distinguishes two forms of hypothetico-deductivism :

- one form that looks for a confirmation of theories through empirical tests
- falsificationism.

My question is : ***how is it possible for hypothetico-deductivism not to be falsificationist***?  it seems to me that if I reason by saying that " hypothesis H implies event E, but E occurs, then H is confirmed" this amounts to making an *inductive* inference.

Put another way : is not the " confirmation " approach essentially tied to inductivism ( understood as a probabilist view of scientific theories) ?

Source :

- whole syllabus : [http://people.loyno.edu/~folse/236syl.html](http://people.loyno.edu/%7Efolse/236syl.html)
- hypothetico-deductivism : [http://people.loyno.edu/~folse/HypDeduc5.html](http://people.loyno.edu/%7Efolse/HypDeduc5.html)

Comment: Hypothetico-deductive is a mixture of deductive and inductive, the "deductive" historically just referred to deducing what a general hypothesis was supposed to predict about a specific testable situation, prior to actually performing the empirical test (the inductive part). See discussion of "deductions" of a theory on [p. 216 of this 1937 article](https://books.google.com/books?id=__U0AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA216) for example. Folse seems to be distinguishing this from hopes for a "purely" inductive method where one tries to formulate laws based just on observations with no prior theories.

Comment: It is, see e.g. [IEP, Hypothetico-Deductive Confirmation](https://iep.utm.edu/conf-ind/#SH3b) or [Philosophy and the practice of Bayesian statistics by Gelman and Shalizi](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4476974/). Popper's anti-inductive maximalism was never particularly convincing.